# Unresolved reference: packageName in android studio(kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am making a user profile fragment for my application and I have been getting an error in my imageUri

```
private fun uploadProfilePicture(){
        imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.drawable.placeholderprofile}")
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+auth.currentUser?.uid)
        storageReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Save successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Upload image failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Why does it not recognize $packageName?

I have tried rebuilding and cleaning, gradle sync, and invalidating caches.

Comment: Can you try this? `activity?.packageName` instead? so it will become `${activity?.packageName}`

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? `activity?.packageName` instead? so it will become `${activity?.packageName}`

```
imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${activity?.packageName}/${R.drawable.placeholderprofile}")
```